# Measuring distance between points yet within polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, network-analyst

I have two data sets. One has points of populations and the other has one merged polygon of all suitable habitat types.

I want to find the distance between all the point to one another, but without exiting the polygon. So the route would have to go around any holes in the polygon. I cannot add network to the polygon so I do not know if this is possible.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps review our [self-assembling FAQ on finding Least Cost Paths in ArcGIS Desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cost-path+arcgis-desktop?sort=frequent).

Comment: A picture would go a long way toward understanding this problem. Something is certainly possible, but you should include the exact ArcGIS software release, the license level, and which extensions you have available, within the question body.

Comment: Using python create a line feature class for each combination of point pairs then select from that feature class all lines that are completely within the polygon and export to a new feature class. Is some python an option for you?